# How to push data to array with position [i]?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example i've created an array in a for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   array[i] = {
     label: bread,
     color: colorArray[i]
   };
 }
```

In a child for loop i'd like to append more data to this array. What I tried:

```
for (r = 0; r < data[i].length; r++){

   array[i].push({
      data: breadTypes[r][i]
   });
}
```

Which throws `TypeError : array[i].push is not a function.`

`array[r] = { data: breadTypes[r][i] };` overwrites the existing data as expected.

Is there a different way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: use `array.splice(index, i, {
      data: breadTypes[r][i]
   });`  to insert item to index `i`

Comment: Simply remove `[i]`

Comment: Are you looking for `array[i].data = breadTypes[r][i]`?

Comment: `push` is an operation on an array. `data[i]` is not an array, it's an object.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the suggested original, OP isn't trying to insert an item into the array, they're looking to add data to existing objects in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, your second `for` should look like this:

```
for (r = 0; r < data[i].length; r++){
    array[i].data = breadTypes[r][i];
}
```

Comment: That will re-write `array[i].data` `data[i].length - 1` times. What's the point? You should use `array[i].data.push(breadTypes[r][i])`. And define `array[i].data = []` outside of `for (r = 0; r < data[i].length; r++)`

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    array[i].data = breadTypes[i];
}
```

Comment: I have 2 bread objects that each has a lot of dataTypes. Thats why I need 2 for loops to  first get those 2 bread objects and then add the dataTypes to those objects accordingly..

Answer (score 1):

Here `array[i]` is an object and `push` is an array method which cannot be used on an object but you can create `data` key in `array[i]` object

`array[r].data = breadTypes[r]`;

If the second loop is not nested inside the first one then `breadTypes[r][i]` will throw an error since `i` will be be available